# Why does pip not show anything in my virtual environment for Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, pip, python-venv

I create a python virtual environment and then try to run pip on it. But pip doesn't show anything; like it doesn't work in my virtual environment.

I tried to run it like this:

```
PS D:\\api_enchant\> venv/bin/activate.ps1

(venv) PS D:\\api_enchant\> pip list

(venv) PS D:\\api_enchant\> pip

(venv) PS D:\\api_enchant\> django-admin

(venv) PS D:\\api_enchant\> python manage.py runserver

(venv) PS D:\\api_enchant\>
```

The terminal doesn't show any response then.

I want to work with my API within this virtual environment; please help me.